# Framework/ Library to compare/assert data across platforms

Tags: java, validation, etl

I am looking for a Library/Framework/Tool preferably written in Java that can act as a data validator for comparing data across relational database platforms. Post ETL transformations, I need means to compare source and target data for integrity. The tool I found was https://github.com/ExpediaGroup/quibble but I need an alternative to this that is preferably still maintained, has better written documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose such tools as QuerySurge (https://www.querysurge.com/),
or ETL Validator (https://www.datagaps.com/etl-testing-tools/etl-validator/),
or any other tool that is mentioned in this link(https://www.guru99.com/etl-testing-tools.html),
however if you desire an open source data validation tool,
you should try https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services-data-validator

Hope I've been helpful,
R

Comment: Not sure why this question and the answer has received downvotes, but professional-services-data-validator works as per my use case. Thanks